# webpack dev server CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cors, webpack-dev-server, superagent

I am using `webpack-dev-server v1.10.1` to boost up my Redux project and I have the options below:

```
contentBase: `http://${config.HOST}:${config.PORT}`,
quiet: false,
noInfo: true,
hot: true,
inline: true,
lazy: false,
publicPath: configWebpack.output.publicPath,
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
stats: {colors: true}
```

In the JS, I am using `request` from `superagent` to generate a HTTP GET call

```
request
          .get(config.APIHost + apiUrl)
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .withCredentials()
          .end(function (err, res) {
                if (!err && res.body) {
                    disptach(() => {
                        return {
                            type: actionType || GET_DATA,
                            payload: {
                                response: res.body
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
          });
```

But I got the CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/getContentByType?category=all. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5050' is therefore not allowed access
```

Any suggestion to resolve this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 105):

Another way to work around it is to directly add the required CORS headers to the dev server:

```
devServer: {
  ...
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
}
```

#### Doc links

- [Webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header)

Comment: Any links to where you found this?

Comment: It's in the webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-

Comment: Adding this doesn't work for me, nothing changes. Still I get error of missing access-control-allow-headers header.

Comment: Usually it's enough to just put "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" there.

Comment: If you also use a browser through some redirection (proxy, ssh redirect, …), use the devServer option `sockPort: 'location'`, so the socket port will use the same as the location port, which is usually enough.

Comment: @prk_001 Try specifying the allowed hosts. Under `headers: ...`, add `allowedHosts: ["localhost", ".host.com", "host2.com", "subdomain.host3.com"]`. The `.host.com` entry is a wildcard for any subdomain on that domain. You can aslo use `"auto"`, which you can read about [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts).

Answer (score 54):

With webpack-dev-server 1.15.X you can use this configuration in your config file:

```
devServer: {
   contentBase: DIST_FOLDER,
   port: 8888,
   // Send API requests on localhost to API server get around CORS.
   proxy: {
      '/api': {
         target: {
            host: "0.0.0.0",
            protocol: 'http:',
            port: 8080
         },
         pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': ''
         }
      }
   }
},
```

With this example you will redirect all calls from `http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/*` to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/*` and CORS solved

Comment: This is not working for me. Still getting the exception saying Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:7000'. I intentionaly added 'http://localhost:7000' in back end. Just to verify that if proxy is working on my front end, this setting will not restrict my api call.

Comment: It had been a bit different issue I believe, but apparently just setting `port: 8080` was enough for me. I just wanted to enable 'hot reload' (while using Vue).
Thank You anyway!

Comment: I like this solution, because as far as I can see this setup is closest to typical production setups, where e.g. an appropriate NGINX config would similarly unify the frontend + backend under the same origin.

Comment: This worked for me. But! In my API, I also use the websockets. To allow websockets to be passed through proxy, add `ws: true` to `'/api'` node.

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue, but my api was on a https protocol (https://api....). Had to start the server with https and use https://localhost:8080

```js
devServer: {
    https: true,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    // ....
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

You're running your JavaScript from `localhost:5050` but your API server is `localhost:8000`. This violates the same origin policy, so the browser disallows it.

You can either modify your API server so that [CORS is enabled](http://enable-cors.org/), or follow [the instructions on the webpack-dev-server page](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server) under "Combining with an existing server" to combine asset serving with webpack-dev-server and your own API server.

Comment: The second link is now broken

Comment: This is the official documentation.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 solutions for this. first one is setting up proxy on the client side, second one is setting CORS on the server. CORS is server issue, server does not allow access from different source. Even using different ports is considered to be different source

**First Solution**

IN your backend code, you have to set this headers: this is example of in express node.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

**Second Solution:**

in webpack config.js, if you want to pass any variable, we export

```
module.exports=function(env){
return {}}
```

instead of

```
module.exports={}
```

we inject this `env` through the script.

```
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --env.api='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'",
```

now webpack has access to this env. in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = function ({
  api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
}) {
  return {
    entry: { main: "./src/index.js" },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
      filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    mode: "development",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
        },
        
        {
          // Load other files, images etc
          test: /\.(png|j?g|gif|ico)?$/,
          use: "url-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    //Some JavaScript bundlers may wrap the application code with eval statements in development.
    //If you use Webpack, using the cheap-module-source-map setting in development to avoid this problem
    devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      proxy: {
        "/api": {
          changeOrigin: true,
          cookieDomainRewrite: "localhost",
          target: api,
          onProxyReq: (proxyReq) => {
            if (proxyReq.getHeader("origin")) {
              proxyReq.setHeader("origin", api);
            }
          },
        },
      },
    },
    
  };
};
```