# Shopware 6: bin/watch-storefront.sh causes CORS errors in chrome

Tags: webpack, cors, shopware

When trying to develop the store front, we use `bin/watch-storefront.sh`

Our APP URL is http://ourshop.localhost.example.com and we have a DNS entry which points to 127.0.0.1

Now when opening the printed URL http://ourshop.localhost.example.com:9998 most of the AJAX requests do not work due to CORS errors.

This seems because the site now running at URL `http://ourshop.localhost.example.com:9998` is requesting data from `http://ourshop.localhost.example.com` (for example when paginating throw the product filters / list.

We already tried changing the APP_URL to `http://ourshop.localhost.example.com:9998` but it does not help.

How can this be solved?

*EDIT*

The interesting part is, that `bin/watch-administration.sh` does not suffer from this problems. It servers on http://localhost:8080/ and works without CORS problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602697/webpack-dev-server-cors-issue

Comment: If the origin (top address bar) is different than the URL in the AJAX call (protocol + domain + port), CORS will kick in. You need to focus your troubleshooting on why the AJAX calls aren't based on the APP_URL variable.

Comment: @Megabit I think they are based on the APP_URL variable, but webpack is proxying the requests, and thus the URL is different?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to call Chrome with CORS disabled

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp/user$$
```

But I am looking for better solutions.